# Why use dir_index, filetype, and sparse_super with LUKS volumes?

Tags: luks, mkfs

I have been reviewing various HOWTOs and blog posts about encrypted LUKS volumes formatted with ext3.  Every single document specifies mkfs with: `-O dir_index,filetype,sparse_super` and not one of them explains why.

I have a rough idea what dir_index does.  What I am looking for is an explanation of why these three options specifically would be so universally accepted as a good idea for encrypted filesystems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the `-o` flag dictates the 'options' switch.

> Flags Item    Description
>
> -b Boot   Names the program to be installed in block 0 of the new file system.
>
> -i i-Nodes    Specifies the initial number of i-nodes on the file system. This flag is ignored when creating a journaled file system.
>
> -l Label  Specifies the file system label for the new file system.
>
> -o Options    Specifies a comma-separated list of virtual file system implementation-specific options.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/mkfs.htm

Comment: That completely sidesteps the question.  I'm not asking what -O does.  I'm asking why the options dir_index, filetype, and sparse_super are used so frequently in mkfs examples pertaining to LUKS volumes.